# socket IO between netns

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am exploring Python `socket` support with Linux network-namespaces, I see there is `pyroute2`, which handles only network-namespace (`netns`) creation etc, but does not seem to have any APIs for `socket` IO (say `udp`).

And the Python `socket` library also does not seem to have any methods 
related to pick a specific network-namespace .

Am I missing something, or its not yet implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently there was `setns()` call introduced in `pyroute2`, that allows you to set the network namespace for the current process. Then you can spawn processes with `multiprocessing`, set NS for each and use `multiprocessing.Pipe` to communicate between spawned processes.

If anything else is still missing — ye're welcome to file an issue at github, we'll try to fix it asap.